# Subset list of vectors with vector of positions

Tags: r, vector, subset, lapply

I have a list of vectors (`mylist`):

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4)
b <- c(5,6,7,8)
c <- c(9,10,11,12)
mylist <- list(a,b,c)
```

I also have a vector of positions (`mypos`):

```
mypos <- c(1,2,3)
```

I would like to use `mypos` to give the position of elements to subset each vector of `mypos` so that it returns:

```
 [1] 1 6 11
```

I have tried using lapply like this:

```
lapply(mylist, "[", mypos)
```

but this returns elements 1, 2 and 3 of each vector:

```
[[1]]
 [1] 1 2 3

[[2]]
 [1] 5 6 7

[[3]] 
 [1] 9 10 11
```

I have also tried:

```
lapply(mylist, subset, mypos)
```

But this returns an error that the subset must be logical

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can use `Map` to extract the corresponding elements of 'mylist' from the index of 'mypos'

```
Map(`[`, mylist, mypos)
```

---

In the OP's code, the 'mypos' is repeated in each of `list` elements resulting in extracting all the elements from the index.  Instead it could be looped on sequence

```
lapply(seq_along(mylist), function(x) mylist[[x]][mypos[[x]]])
```

Comment: `mapply(\`[\`, mylist, mypos)` assuming they're fine with the results being combined.

Comment: This is the one, thank you. I will definitely read up on `Map()` for future use.